# Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Unexpected node when typescript upgrade to 2.1.1

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack

when i upgrade typescript from 2.0.3 to 2.1.1, get errors:

```
 [at-loader] Using typescript@2.1.1 from typescript and "tsconfig.json" from /Users/zhouweiming/data/project/iermu_opssite/src/tsconfig.json

/Users/zhouweiming/data/project/iermu_opssite/src/node_modules/.typescript@2.1.1/lib/typescript.js:59508
            throw e;
            ^

Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Unexpected node.
Verbose Debug Information: Node 94 (NullKeyword) was unexpected.
at Object.assert (/Users/zhouweiming/data/project/iermu_opssite/src/node_modules/.typescript@2.1.1/lib/typescript.js:3001:23)
at Object.Debug.failBadSyntaxKind (/Users/zhouweiming/data/project/iermu_opssite/src/node_modules/.typescript@2.1.1/lib/typescript.js:42746:55)
at serializeTypeNode (/Users/zhouweiming/data/project/iermu_opssite/src/node_modules/.typescript@2.1.1/lib/typescript.js:44666:30)
at serializeTypeNode (/Users/zhouweiming/data/project/iermu_opssite/src/node_modules/.typescript@2.1.1/lib/typescript.js:44637:56)
at serializeTypeOfNode (/Users/zhouweiming/data/project/iermu_opssite/src/node_modules/.typescript@2.1.1/lib/typescript.js:44498:28)
at serializeParameterTypesOfNode (/Users/zhouweiming/data/project/iermu_opssite/src/node_modules/.typescript@2.1.1/lib/typescript.js:44550:42)
at addOldTypeMetadata (/Users/zhouweiming/data/project/iermu_opssite/src/node_modules/.typescript@2.1.1/lib/typescript.js:44425:136)
at addTypeMetadata (/Users/zhouweiming/data/project/iermu_opssite/src/node_modules/.typescript@2.1.1/lib/typescript.js:44416:17)
at transformAllDecoratorsOfDeclaration (/Users/zhouweiming/data/project/iermu_opssite/src/node_modules/.typescript@2.1.1/lib/typescript.js:44241:13)
at generateConstructorDecorationExpression (/Users/zhouweiming/data/project/iermu_opssite/src/node_modules/.typescript@2.1.1/lib/typescript.js:44351:40)
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "es6", "es2015"],
    "rootDirs": ["./"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "./public/*"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/*",
    "config/helpers.js",
    "config/webpack.common.js",
    "config/webpack.dev.js",
    "config/webpack.prod.js",
    "webpack.config.js",
    "gulpfile.js"
  ]
}
```

`other env`:

- webpack: 1.13.3
- node: 7.2.0
- angular: 2.2.4
- awesome-typescript-loader: 3.0.0-beta.9

and in my project, when i use @Injectable() before Class definition, vscode output error:

```
 [ts] Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.
```

when i remove @Injectable() decorator in my all codes, all error disappear on compile my project, but run fail in browser, because inject module fail.

Comment: remove `files` from tsconfig.json, vscode has no error.

Comment: I have already submitted one issue to typescript develop group on github. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12684#issuecomment-265116501